# How to group provided string correctly?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
^([A-Za-z]{2,3}\d{6}|\d{5}|\d{3})((\d{3})?)(\d{2}|\d{3}|\d{6})(\d{2}|\d{3})$
```

I use this regex to match different, yet similar strings:

```
# MOR644-004-007-001
MOR644004007001 # string provided
# VUF00101-050-08-01
VUF001010500801 # string provided
# MF001317-077944-01
MF00131707794401 # string provided
```

These strings need to match/group as it is at the top of the strings, however my problem is that it is not grouping it correctly

The first string: `MOR644004007001` is grouped: `(MOR644004) (007) (001)` which should be `(MOR644) (004) (007) (001)`

The second string: `VUF001010500801` is grouped `(VUF001010) (500) (801)` which should be `(VUF00101) (050) (08) (01)`

How can I change `([A-Za-z]{2,3}\d{6}|\d{5}|\d{3})((\d{3})?)` so that it would group the provided string correctly?

Comment: how do you distinguish `MOR644004007001` from `VUF001010500801` ??

Comment: I can't make out the pattern you want to group this by. Can you clarify why the first group in ex1 is 6 characters and in the second example it is 8 characters long?

Comment: Seems like you have 2-3 alpha, followed by 7-18 digits. You need to express the rules for splitting up those digits, either in the regex, or afterwards. regex are greedy, so earlier groups will take digits when there is a choice.

Comment: @PruthviRaj If you look at the commented strings with `-` in, they are structured differently, so I am trying to develop a regex that would group these strings so I can add the `-`. does that answer your question?

Comment: @Serv These are pack numbers of stock, different batches have different numbers, but it is kept similar. it is different lengths because it is from different batches.

Comment: Is "MOR001010500801" allowed? How would that be grouped? How do you know how it should be grouped?

Comment: @Renier just by looking at a string, how do you humanly determine if it is going to be split after 6 characters or after 8? If you cannot describe this rule logically without dependencies, you are gonna have a hard time re-phrasing this as a regular expression. That's what I wanted to tell you by asking.

Comment: This is mind-breaking. I could only get to [this](https://regex101.com/r/wX8eO7/1). I hope it will help a bit.

Comment: @Serv thanks for clearing that up. You can determine how many chars before a `-` and how many chars are in the string by looking at the prefix, e/g, `MOR` , `VUF` and `MF`. strings with the same prefix will allways be the same length and format. but I do not know when which string will be provided.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for the possible solution, though its not 100% what I need, it is closer than I could get.

Comment: The problem is that I do not understand what is the requirement for the number of groups. I tried to use conditionals, but I just do not understand what the requirement is. Do you think I should post my solution?

Comment: @stribizhev you can post your solution, I can't see why not. it is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your comment to Serv I'd say the (only?) solution is to have one regex for each possibility, like -

```
MOR(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})|VUF(\d{5})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})|MF(\d{6})(\d{6})(\d{2})
```

and then use the execution environment (JS/php/python - you haven't provided which one) to piece the parts together.

See example on [regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/jG1qF9/3). Note that substitution, only as an example, matches only the second string.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, and help... This seems like a viable solution to my problem.  The execution environment is python, btw.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that you can do what you want to.
Let's consider the first two strings:

```
# MOR644-004-007-001
MOR644004007001 # string provided
# VUF00101-050-08-01
VUF001010500801 # string provided
```

Now, both the strings are composed of 3 chars followed by 12 digits. Thus, given a regex *R*, if *R* does not depend on particular (sequences of) characters and on particular (sequences of) digits (i.e., it presents `[A-Za-z]` and `\d` but does not present, let's say, `MO` and `0070`), then it will match both the string in the same way.

So, if you want to operate a different matching, then you need to look at the particular occurrence of certain characters or digits. We need more data from you in order to give you an aswer.

Finally, I suggest you to take a look at this tool:
http://regex.inginf.units.it/ (demo: http://regex.inginf.units.it/demo.html). It is a research project that automatically generates a regex given (many) examples of extraction. I warmly suggest you to try it, especially if you know that an underlying pattern is present in your case for sure (i.e. strings beginning with `VUF` must be matched differently from strings beginning with `MOR`) but you are unable to find it. Again, you will need to provide many examples to the engine. Needles to say, if a generic pattern does not exist, then the tool won't find it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. I have used what's called as a named group. As pointed out earlier by others, it's better to have one regex code for each string. I have shown here for the first string, `MOR644004007001`. Easily you can expand for other two strings:

```
import re

# MOR644-004-007-001
MOR = "MOR644004007001" # string provided
# VUF00101-050-08-01
VUF = "VUF001010500801" # string provided
# MF001317-077944-01
MF = "MF00131707794401" # string provided

MORcompile = re.compile(r'(?P<first>\w{,6})(?P<second>\d{,3})(?P<third>\d{,3})(?P<fourth>\d{,3})')
MORsearch = MORcompile.search(MOR.strip())
print MORsearch.group('first')
print MORsearch.group('second')
print MORsearch.group('third')
print MORsearch.group('fourth')

MOR644
004
007
001
```